# How to implement Snap Codes like special codes?

Tags: flutter, encoding, qr-code, decoding

I wanted to implement the custom qr code like special codes in my Flutter App.

Like, by scanning the code with my app user will get the resulting profile page. Like if my user id in the app is `userX` and some user `userY` scans my profile code (the special qr code) the USER Y will be redirected to USER X's profile.

So, I wanted to implement this special QR code like codes, my own design, my app's logo in it, around some binary dots or things, encoded a bit of data like the profile id.

How can I do this? Is there any reference for this? Thanks!